# Why isn't Tailwind CSS connecting in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am attempting to install tailwind (Which I have done many times before with no issue). Please help me with what I am missing this time around.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Package.json

```
....
  "devDependencies": {
    .....
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  },
....
```

index.js

```
import './index.css'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

app.js

```
const App = () => {
  return <div className='bg-blue-300'>
    cool
  </div> 
}
```

And lastly (where I believe my problem is)
index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body{
    background-color: red; /* I WORK FYI! */
}
```

(EDIT) A bit more info: This app is the 'example-app' generated after running using `create-react-library`. I just created a brand new react app, installed TW, and had no problems. I also installed another package into my example-app (react-icons) just to test that wasn't the issue but that works as expected.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you start the Tailwind CLI build process?

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Comment: I don't as I have never had to do this before? This is a react app so `npm run start` makes the magic happen (usually).